# Manage the identity used by an Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I run an Azure DevOps pipeline, the pipeline may run using Project Collection Build Service ([organization]) or [project] Build Service ([organization]). Is there a way to choose which one is to be used? Moreover, is there a way to know which user identity was used in a pipeline run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to choose which one is to be used? Moreover, is there a way to know which user identity was used in a pipeline run?

Yes, you can refer to the following steps to confirm the user identity used in pipeline run.

Step1: You can check the option: **Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines** in **Project Settings -> Settings.**

[image]

If the option is enable, all pipelines (YAML Pipeline or Classic Pipeline) will use the Project level build service (**[project] Build Service ([organization])**)  in Pipeline run.

Step2: If the option is disabled, the YAML Pipelines will use the Organization Level Build service(**Project Collection Build Service ([organization])**).

For the Classic Pipeline, you need to navigate to **Pipeline definition -> Options -> Build job authorization scope** and check the scope.

For example:

[image]

If the value is **Project Collection**, the classic pipeline will use the Organization Level Build service(**Project Collection Build Service ([organization])**)

If the value is **Current Project**, the classic pipeline will use the Project level build service (**[project] Build Service ([organization])**).

**Note:** If the pipeline needs to access the resources in other projects, you need to disable the option: **Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines** in **Project Settings -> Settings.**. Then Yaml Pipeline will use Organization Level Build service to access the resource and classic pipeline will access the resource based on the scope settings.